# working at each iteration g_hash_table_foreach

Tags: c, glib

I wish to loop through every key value pair within my hashtable. Therefore I used the g_hash_table_foreach() function (Prototype shown below). For each key value pair, it calls a **void** func method.

```
void g_hash_table_foreach(GHashTable *hash_table,GHFunc func,
                          gpointer user_data);
```

However, I require that for every call to the function, the method **returns** a value back.

For example consider the following code:

```
void calculate(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
    return calculateNumbers(key, value);
}

int total = 0;
g_hash_table_foreach(mymap, calculate, NULL);
```

I require that the variable total stores the total of each returned value received by the calculate() function. I am finding it difficult to do this with the g_hash_table_foreach method.

I would rather have a while loop, declare the total variable outside and increase its value with every iteration over each pair. However, I dont think glib allows to me conider a key-value pair one at a time. (Unlike the GList with has the next attribute) Any ideas how I can do this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's why the API gives you a "user pointer". Pass whatever data you need there, for instance the address of the `total` variable:

```
static void calculate(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
    int *total = userdata;

    *total += calculateNumbers(key, value);
}

g_hash_table_foreach(mymap, calculate, &total);
```

The glib and GTK+ API:s are very good at providing user pointers, which has left me "spoiled"; whenever a see a C API involving callbacks that doesn't (forcing the programmer to use global state) I cringe. And complain. And, if possible, fix it.

**UPDATE**: Also, for completeness' sake, you actually can do this without the callback, using the GHashTable's "iteration" API.

See the [`g_hash_table_iter_init()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-iter-init) and [`g_hash_table_iter_next()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-iter-next) functions. These require at least glib version 2.16.

Comment: Ok thank you, it works now =) Still new to the API. Thanks again:)